# Error On vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

```
vector<int> :: iterator itr1;
cin >> query;
for(i = 0; i < query ; i++)
{
    cin >> checknum;
    if (binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), checknum))
    {
        itr1 = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), checknum);
        cout << "Yes " << itr1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        itr1 = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), checknum);
        cout << "No " << itr1 << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error during compilation: Compile Message

```
solution.cc: In function 'int main()':
solution.cc:28:18: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
             cout << "Yes " << itr1 << endl;
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
                 from solution.cc:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]'
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
solution.cc:33:18: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
             cout << "No " << itr1 << endl;
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
                 from solution.cc:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]'
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

Comment: You can probably narrow this down to 2 lines of code. Most of what you posted is irrelevant.

Comment: So what is the question?  Besides that you probably want to use `*itr1` in that `cout` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound` returns an `std::vector<int>::iterator`, you cannot print it using `cout`.

Probably you meant:

```
cout << "Yes " << *itr1 << endl;
cout << "No " << *itr1 << endl;
```

Comment: It doesn't even matter what `lower_bound` returns. The irrelevant code got to you too!

Answer (score 0):

An iterator cannot be passed to `std::cout`.

To get the proper position, we need to subtract `v.begin()` from `itr1`, 
i.e:

```
cout << distance(v.begin(), itr1) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print position, you should do something like this.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator low,up;
low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); 
up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); 

std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << '\n';
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Why the down-vote?  OK.  It would be nicer to write `const auto low = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 20);` but the basic answer is right.

Comment: I am a bit concerned, can i do anything about it

Comment: Thnx for link, i was searching but was unable to find it

Comment: `low - v.begin()` and `up - v.begin()` produce iterators, which cannot be passed to `std:cout`. If you want to output the vector index that `low` and `up` represent, use `std::distance()`, eg: `std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << std::distance(v.begin(), low) << std::endl;`